# Как перевести сообщения модулей в Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, i18n

Здравствуйте.
Использую Yii2 Basic. Установил модуль [dektrium/yii2-user](https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user), и все сообщения во view которые не касаются модуля переводятся нормально (скажем статьи, контакты), а вот страница входа, восстановления пароля, регистрация и т.д - все на оригинальном языке.

Еще интересно то, что если я в переопределенной (overriden) вьюхе напишу 
`<?= Yii::t('app', 'Join'); ?>` - то все-равно выводится "Join".

[В документацию](https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/tutorial-i18n/#perevod-soobsenij-modulej) смотрел, но не понимаю где создать файл с этим кодом.

Вопроса два:

1. Как перевести сообщения от модуля, типа "Вы ввели неправильный пароль", "Введите E-mail" и т.д? Тоесть сообщения валидации.
2. Как перевести просто текст во view, если этот view был переопределен вот таким вот образом в config/web.php

   ```
       'view' => [
       'theme' => [
           'pathMap' => [
               '@dektrium/user/views' => '@app/views/user/'

           ],
       ],
   ],
   ```

Спасибо огромное!